# Use avahi4j zeroconf to discover multiple machines running the same service

Tags: java, scala, avahi

I'm trying to use avahi4j zeroconf to find multiple hosts that offer the same service. When running a very simple test on my machine, I don't see any of the callbacks for new services (`IServiceBrowserCallback`) nor for service resolution (`IServiceResolverCallback`). For example, I have the following code (essentially just copied from some example code online, plus reading the apis from the javadoc):

```
object AvahiBootstapMain {

  class Publisher(client: Client, group: EntryGroup) {

    def close() = {
      group.reset
      client.release
    }
  }

  def newPublisher(): Publisher = {
    val client = new Client
    client.start
    val group: EntryGroup = client.createEntryGroup
    val txtRecords = List("asdfasdf" + Math.random())
    group.addService(Avahi4JConstants.AnyInterface,
      Protocol.ANY,
      "myName",
      "_test._tcp",
      null,
      null,
      1515,
      txtRecords);
    group.commit
    new Publisher(client, group)
  }

  def newServiceBrowser(): Unit = {
    val client = new Client
    client.start
    val browserCallback = new IServiceBrowserCallback {
      def serviceCallback(interfaceNum: Int,
                          proto: Avahi4JConstants.Protocol,
                          browserEvent: Avahi4JConstants.BrowserEvent,
                          name: String,
                          typ: String,
                          domain: String,
                          lookupResultFlag: Int) = {
        val args = Map(
          "ifNum" -> interfaceNum,
          "proto" -> proto,
          "browserEvent" -> browserEvent,
          "name" -> name,
          "type" -> typ,
          "domain" -> domain,
          "lookupResultFlag" -> lookupResultFlag)
        println(s"browserCallback: $args")
      }
    }
    client.createServiceBrowser(
      browserCallback,
      Avahi4JConstants.AnyInterface,
      Protocol.ANY,
      "_test._tcp",
      null,
      0)
  }

  def newServiceResolver(): Unit = {
    val client = new Client
    client.start
    val resolverCallback = new IServiceResolverCallback {
      def resolverCallback(resolver: ServiceResolver,
                           interfaceNum: Int,
                           proto: Avahi4JConstants.Protocol,
                           resolverEvent: ServiceResolver.ServiceResolverEvent,
                           name: String,
                           typ: String,
                           domain: String,
                           hostname: String,
                           address: Address,
                           port: Int,
                           txtRecords: Array[String],
                           lookupResultFlag: Int) = {
        val args = Map(
          "ifNum" -> interfaceNum,
          "proto" -> proto,
          "resolverEvent" -> resolverEvent,
          "name" -> name,
          "type" -> typ,
          "domain" -> domain,
          "hostname" -> hostname,
          "address" -> address,
          "port" -> port,
          "txtRecords" -> txtRecords.toList,
          "lookupResultFlag" -> lookupResultFlag)
        println(s"resolverCallback: $args")
      }
    }
    client.createServiceResolver(
      resolverCallback,
      Avahi4JConstants.AnyInterface,
      Protocol.ANY,
      "myName",
      "_test._tcp",
      null,
      Protocol.ANY,
      0)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val p = newPublisher()
    newServiceBrowser()
    newServiceResolver()
    System.in.read()
    p.close()
  }
}
```

No matter how many concurrently running applications I have on my machine, the callbacks for service discovery are only called once:

```
Avahi4J v0.1-0
browserCallback: Map(name -> null, domain -> null, ifNum -> -1, proto -> ANY, lookupResultFlag -> 0, type -> _test._tcp, browserEvent -> CACHE_EXHAUSTED)
browserCallback: Map(name -> null, domain -> null, ifNum -> -1, proto -> ANY, lookupResultFlag -> 0, type -> _test._tcp, browserEvent -> NO_MORE)
browserCallback: Map(name -> myName, domain -> local, ifNum -> 2, proto -> INET6, lookupResultFlag -> 12, type -> _test._tcp, browserEvent -> NEW)
browserCallback: Map(name -> myName, domain -> local, ifNum -> 2, proto -> INET, lookupResultFlag -> 12, type -> _test._tcp, browserEvent -> NEW)
resolverCallback: Map(name -> myName, resolverEvent -> RESOLVER_FOUND, hostname -> ubuntu-2.local, domain -> local, ifNum -> 2, proto -> INET6, lookupResultFlag -> 13, port -> 1515, txtRecords -> List(asdfasdf0.6048590915795314), address -> IPv6: fe80::20c:29ff:fe7d:7c42, type -> _test._tcp)
```

Does anyone have any idea why these services are not discovering each other? Am I doing something wrong? If it's any help, I can see multiple services if I give them different names (in which case I can see multiple browse events -- however it seems I would have to create a new resolver for each name if I wanted to get more detailed information about each of the services for which the browser callback is fired).